Correct Preposition to Use After "Blow Up"
Do I say "blew up in a deafening sound" or "blew up with a deafening sound"?

Your question lacks clarity. It is not a sentence and it is unclear what is doing the "blowing up" or the context in which the "blowing up" takes place. Please edit to include the necessary details.

The choice of preposition is usually dependent on its object (the part of the sentence that the preposition introduces) rather than its complement or antecedent (the part that comes before it). Most prepositions have multiple uses/meanings, but "in" can introduce the manner in which something happens. You could say, for example, "it exploded in a shower of debris", because the resultant debris is part of the thing ("it") that exploded. However, the sound created by an explosion is not the 'manner' in which it exploded. The sound created by an explosion is dependent on other factors - explosions underwater may produce a muffled sound, for example; explosions in a vacuum may not make any noise. So, it would be wrong to use "in" in your example as written because the sound and the explosion are not the same thing. "It blew up with a deafening sound" is correct as the sound created is an accompanying action.
You could instead use an adjective like 'loud' or an adverb like 'loudly' to directly describe the explosion itself rather than the sound it created, for example "it exploded loudly", or "it was a deafening explosion".
